# Wordpress - display widget

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a custom theme and in my contact page i want to add a widget to display google maps map throught Wp Google Map plugin but i can't show the map in my page.

In my functions.php i have this:

```js
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'My_Widgtet_Area',
        'id' => 'map-area',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
}
```

In my html file:

```html
<?php
  $map = get_page_by_title( 'Mapa' );
  echo $map->post_content;
?>
```

In my page content:

```html
[wpgmza id="1"]
```

How can i display or associate the widget to my page?

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the map directly using the given shortcode or you can add the shortcode in the widget and add the widget in page.

To add the map directly in the page using shortcode

```
echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id="1"]');
```

To add widget in the page

```
dynamic_sidebar('map-area');
```

Hope it helps...

Please ask if you have any doubts.